# In Word 2016, how to apply italics while typing, using underscore

Tags: microsoft-word, markdown

In older Word versions, there was an option somewhere to auto-apply emphasis (*italics* and **bold**), so that when typing a word or a sentence enclosed with the underscore character (`_`), that word or sentence would automatically have italics applied, while typing (same with `*` for bold).

So for example if you typed `_test_`, when you typed the second underscore the word `test` would become italicized (and the underscore characters removed).

I can't seem to find that option in Word 2016. Has it been removed? If not, where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to *File > Word Options > Proofing > AutoCorrect Options... > AutoFormat As You Type* then enable `*Bold* and _italic_ with real formatting`

[image: AutoFormat As You Type]

Comment: Thank you. (In fact apparently I'm using Office 365, and the screen above is found in File/Options/Proofing/AutoCorrect options/AutoFormat As You Type.)